# struts2 file upload-getting null file name

Tags: jakarta-ee, file-upload, struts2, tomcat7

I have trying to upload file but whenever i try to upload the file and print the file-name, i get null and a .tmp file is generated. I followed mkyong's how-to's  [here](http://www.mkyong.com/struts2/struts-2-file-upload-example/).I also tried suggestions from SO in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20733554/struts-2-file-upload-file-object-being-null).Unfortunately,i am still stuck in this one and suppose i made a mistake which i am continuously overlooking.I am using tomcat7.
 Following are my files :

**jsp**

```
<s:form id="login" name="login" method="post" action="uploadResume" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <s:file name="uploadFile" label="Select a File to upload" size="40"/>
    <s:submit value="submit" name="submit" />
</s:form>
```

**struts.xml**

```
    <constant name="struts.multipart.saveDir" value="/Users/shibasish/Documents/workspace/MSVenture/src/main/resources" />
<action name="uploadResume" class="com.msventure.web.actions.CompleteProfileAction" method="uploadResume">
            <interceptor-ref name="exception"/>
                <interceptor-ref name="i18n"/>
                <interceptor-ref name="fileUpload">
                <param name="allowedTypes">text/plain</param>
                <param name="maximumSize">10240</param>
            </interceptor-ref>
                <result name="success">/profile.jsp</result>
                <result name="fail">/login.jsp</result>
                <result name="index">/index.jsp</result>
                  <result name="login">/talent.jsp</result>
            </action>
```

**action-class**

```
        private File uploadFile;
    private String uploadFileFileName;
    public String uploadResume(){
            try{
            String filePath = "/Users/shibasish/Documents";
            System.out.println("Server path:" + filePath);
            System.out.println("File Name:" + uploadFileFileName);
            File fileToCreate = new File(filePath, uploadFileFileName);          
            FileUtils.copyFile(uploadFile, fileToCreate);
            }catch(Exception e){}       
            return "success";
        }
public File getUploadFile() {
        return uploadFile;
    }

    public void setUploadFile(File uploadFile) {
        this.uploadFile = uploadFile;
    }

    public String getUploadFileFileName() {
        return uploadFileFileName;
    }

    public void setUploadFileFileName(String uploadFileFileName) {
        this.uploadFileFileName = uploadFileFileName;
    }
```

**pom.xml**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Please note mutators are set in the class.

Comment: Across all browsers?

Comment: Yes..i tried in chrome and safari.i am currently running it in tomcat7

Comment: Did you try with a more-complete interceptor stack as a sanity check?

Comment: that's what the actual issue was.I was trying the same and you commented..Thanks. :)

Answer (score 0):

I tried with a more complete interceptor stack and it is working fine.
I have changed the following from **file-upload** to **defaultStack interceptor**:
**struts.xml**

```
<action name="uploadResume" class="com.msventure.web.actions.CompleteProfileAction" method="uploadResume">
            <interceptor-ref name="defaultStack">
    <param name="fileUpload.allowedTypes">text/plain</param>
</interceptor-ref> 
        <result name="success">/profile.jsp</result>
        <result name="fail">/login.jsp</result>
        <result name="index">/index.jsp</result>
          <result name="login">/talent.jsp</result>
    </action>
```